# Modal opens on page load

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

so I have a modal on my site and it opens fine and everything but there is one problem ... it opens for a second then closes on page load. How can I fix this? It is powered by CSS and not JavaScript. The button you press to open the modal is included in my navigation bar.

Modal HTML:

```
<div id="JoinUs" data-toggle="modal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h4>Join Us!</h4>

          <input type="text" id="fieldUser" class="input" required pattern=.*\S.* />
          <label for="fieldUser" class="label">Username</label>


          <input type="password" id="fieldPassword" class="input" required pattern=.*\S.* />
          <label for="fieldPassword" class="label">Password</label>

          <button class="btn">Login</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Modal CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background:  #2ecc71; }
```

Comment: It must be something else on your page conflicting with it, assuming you're opening the page with the `#JoinUs` anchor; my test case works as expected:  http://s.codepen.io/angeliquejw/debug/MyoeQb#JoinUs ([Code here](http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/MyoeQb?editors=1100))

Comment: Seems reasonable it is shortly visible since the modal markup is visible - actually we would expect that (before some javascript modal code goes into action and hide `.modalDialog` elements I guess?)  You could set a initial `visibility: hidden` on `.modalDialog`.